# Use regular expression in Pig load command

Tags: apache-pig

I am wondering if it's possible to use regular expression in pig load command to load all files that ends with a suffix. I have see some example for the prefix one. For example if I want to load all the files that start with "Prefix". I can do something like:

```
LOAD '/path/to/dir/Prefix*' USING AvroStorage();
```

For loading all files end with a certain suffix, I am trying to do something like:

```
LOAD '/path/to/dir/*suffix' USING AvroStorage();
```

But it's not working. Can someone please suggest what's wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm able to load files with a suffix using `A = LOAD '/path/to/dir/*suffix' USING PigStorage('|', '-schema');` I don't know why this would work when your example didn't.

Comment: Can you share the error you're seeing?